# php/Codeigniter-- How to compare only date by excluding time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, datetime

i have a field in my db table as `creater_date` as datetime and having values stored in the form of `2013-09-13 02:12:44`

Now i have to compare today-date(no time) with  `creater_date`  table  field .

I tried this below code but it is showing error :

```
 function check_existing_User_weightStatus($u_id)
 {
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('date');  
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $array = array('creater_id' => $u_id,DATE('created_date') => $today);
    $this->db->where($array); 
    $query = $this->db->get('user_weight');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
 }
```

**Getting error :**

```
 A Database Error Occurred

 Error Number: 1064

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '13 Sep 2013 02:48:27 +0530Asia/Calcuttaam30Asia/Calcutta13_13am30Asia/Calcutta '' at line 4

 SELECT * FROM (`user_weight`) WHERE `creater_id` = '3235' AND `2013-09-13T02:48:27+05:30Fri,` 13 Sep 2013 02:48:27 +0530Asia/Calcuttaam30Asia/Calcutta13_13am30Asia/Calcutta '2013-09-13'

 Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\system\database\DB_driver.php

 Line Number: 330
```

*i do not want to compare with the time , i only want to comapare with the today date.    The field `created_date`(eg. 2013-09-13 02:12:44)  is having `datetime` datatypes with some time values. But i want to compare only with the date*

Comment: don't round-trip dates from php to the db. use native comparisons, e.g. `creater_id=curdate()`.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, what do you mean by `don't round-trip dates`? can you please elaborate it?

Comment: consider that PHP may generate the date at 11:59:59pm, but the query won't run until 12:00:00am the next day. don't have PHP generate the date when the DB can do it for you, and use the proper "right then" date.

Comment: @MarcB yeah yeah i got  it. So for this i have to write some sql related code. I think you are well experience person, if you can post a answer for this ,will be very accurate help for me

Comment: mostafa's posted the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code generates a faulty SQL syntax, like the error shows.

I'm not an expert with codeIgniter, but here's how to do a normal query directly, that's probably what you want to do:

```
function check_existing_User_weightStatus($u_id)
 {
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `user_weight` WHERE `creater_id` = '$u_id' AND DATE(`created_date`) = '$today'");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
 }
```

The error in your code is occurring at this line

```
$array = array('creater_id' => $u_id,DATE('created_date') => $today);
```

I'm pretty sure this is not how the where clause will be done, so you might lookup the codeIgniter docs ! to find the right way to do that ! (You're not telling the where clause to use `AND`, `OR`, etc.. operators)

Comment: ah i see, I just updated the code now, let me know how it goes

Comment: you need to give more data, can you show debug info?
or echo the contents of `$query` before it returns true/false ?

Comment: I solved this problem, actually you have to update your code , your above code is not complete.     Add `$today = "'".date('Y-m-d')."'";` this code instead of yours `$today = date('Y-m-d');`  & finally add ` AND finally add this->>  DATE(`created_date`)

Comment: PHP is an interpreted scripting language, it's not compiled in any way, very limited editors can actually do that breakpoint editing..

but you can try xdebug.org it does that or firephp.org

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37290/discussion-between-mostafa-torbjorn-berg-and-user2732367)

Comment: i think now you have to delete all these comment,so that this answer will look clean & neat

Comment: yeah, now its working fine as i wanted But i have added extra 2 new code  to your last edit coded.

Comment: Yeah I approved that and improved it too to make it even simpler to read :) so you don't need the quotes around the date function anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your array  syntax is wrong.

```
<?php $array = array('creater_id'=>$u_id,'DATE(created_date)>=' =>$today);  ?>
```